# Adding a "Printed by"-watermark in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Google couldn't help me, but I know the participants in Super User sometimes have more knowledge then what is publicly available, so to my question: Is there any easy way to add a watermark to an excel 2010 spreadsheet telling which username printed the list?

Kind regards,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to add this to your header or footer.  In Excel 2010 (and 2007 should be similar):

1. Change your view to page layout, `View > Page Layout`.
2. Insert a header (or footer), `Insert > Header & Footer`.
3. On the `Design Tab`, choose either `Header` or `Footer` and that will give you a number of options, including who's actually working on the document.

If you want anything else from your document's custom properties, you'll need to use VBA.  For more info on the necessary VBA, check out Chip Pearson's awesome site:

[Chip Pearson's Document Properties](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/docprop.aspx)

Comment: I think the only name option available in your given steps is to include the name used when Office was installed.  That may be sufficient, but if he's looking to include who's logged in to the computer, it's going to take VBA.

Comment: @techturtle generally you're correct-it's the name in the Options>User Name text box for Excel.  So you can change it, but its not nearly dynamic as using VBA to pull the value from the document properties.

Answer (score 0):

excel 2016 > page layout > print titles >Header/Footer > options  (lower right hand corner) > page setup tab > page options button >  can choose to turn on or off different options for finishes .....date, user name, page number